# Saved user-picked date in local storage gets changed

Tags: javascript, material-ui, local-storage, flatpickr

I'm trying to save the dates entered by the user in local storage and display them the next time the user visits the website. I'm using a datetime picker library called Flatpickr.

Here is the problem: when I pick the dates and save them in local storage, the dates get changed when I reload or close/reopen the page. For example, if I pick 2022-05-02 as my start date, it becomes 2022-05-01 when I refresh the page (same thing happens with the end date).

This is the code for the date picker component (I'm using a page builder called Creative Tim which is built on top of Material UI):

```js
<MDDatePicker
value={minDate}
defaultValue={minDate?.toString()}
options={{ maxDate: maxDate ?? new Date(), allowInput: true }}
input={{
    placeholder: "Select a start date",
    endAdornment: (
    <InputAdornment position="end">
        <IconButton size="small" aria-label="close" color={textColor} onClick={resetImportFromDate}>
        <Icon fontSize="small">clear</Icon>
        </IconButton>
    </InputAdornment>
    ),
}}
onChange={fromDateChange}
/>
```

Here is the `fromDateChange` function:

```
  const fromDateChange = (date) => {
    setMinDate(new Date(date));
    LocalDataStore.set("minDate", date);
  };
```

And here is static `set` method defined on the `LocalDataStore` class:

```
  static set(key, value) {
    let type = typeof value;
    if (value && type !== "undefined") {
      if (type === "object") value = JSON.stringify(value);
      localStorage.setItem(key, crypto.AES.encrypt(value.toString(), key).toString());
    }
  }
```

Comment: This sounds like it could be a timezone conversion issue, are you storing everything in UTC? Have you tried storing e.g. a unix timestamp instead of a date?

Comment: Have you tried sticking a breakpoint / console.log in fromDateChange() — to see if it's getting called on page load?

Comment: @BenjiXVI I did that and although it doesn't get fired upon page reload, it gets called twice when I pick the date the first time.

Comment: @DBS that's possible. FYI, the date always gets pushed back by 1 day. So, if I pick 2022-05-10, it becomes 2022-05-09. Other changes also happen if I open the drop down menu without picking a date.

Comment: Hmm, I think we'd need to see a reproducing example of the problem to be able to help. [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)